# How to use counter excel?

Tags: excel

I have 5000 strings of excel like

```
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
...
```

But I need like:

```
0,./data/images/client_0001 (1).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (2).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (3).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (4).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (5).jpg,1.0
0,./data/images/client_0001 (6).jpg,1.0
...
```

How can I change it? I tried to use counter then I add `0,./data/images/client_0001` at the start and `.jpg,1.0` at the end. But it does not work.

Comment: Are you doing this in VBA or in the Worksheet?  If the latter, why not use `Row()`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I just use it and I paste it for excel

```
def print_hi(name):

    for i in range(614):
        i1 = 249 + i
        i2 = i + 1
        print(str(i1)+',./data/images/imposter_0001 ('+str(i2)+').jpg,0.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).